# How Google AdMob ensures app is not using any other ad service to show ads?

Tags: admob

How Google AdMob ensures app is not using any other ad service  to show ads? An app can use multiple ad services to get ads in his app but only shows specific ads only. How do google know which ads are displayed and whther app is using multiple ad services  or not?